# Vincular bases de datos sql database Azure

Tags: base-de-datos, azure, azure-sql

estoy intentando vincular dos sql database de Azure de manera que a través de uno pueda reverenciar una tabla de otros y actualizarla. Esta funcion en SQL server se realizaba linkeando los servidores, pero en azure no es posible

Comment: Buen día. No comprendo bien que quires decir con _reverenciar_ una tabla de _otros_. ¿De otros qué?. ¿Qué significa, en otras palabras, _reverenciar_ una tabla?

Answer (score 1):

En Azure SQL Database esta funcionalidad se logra mediante "elastic queries", lo que se puede traducir como queries elásticos. En [esta](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/01/05/sample-joining-tables-from-different-azure-sql-databases/?wt.mc_id=MVP) página Web encontrarás un ejemplo completo de cómo hacerlo.

(1) Preparar la conectividad entre la base de datos central y la base de datos externa.

```
/*** EJECUTAR ESTO EN LA BASE DE DATOS DE AZURE SQL QUE CONSIDERES LA BASE DE DATOS CENTRAL ***/
 -- Crear un master key, una "credential" o credencial, y una fuente de datos 
 -- externa
 CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'contraseña_fuerte';
 GO
 CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL ElasticDBQueryCred WITH IDENTITY = 'username', SECRET = 'contraseña_fuerte';
 GO
 CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyElasticDBQueryDataSrc WITH
 (TYPE = RDBMS,
 LOCATION = 'yourserver.database.windows.net',
 DATABASE_NAME = 'YourExternalDatabase',
 CREDENTIAL = ElasticDBQueryCred,
 ) ;
 GO
```

(2) Crear una tabla ejemplo externa y un procedimiento almacenado (stored procedure) para realizar un “join” remoto.:

```
/*** EJECUTAR ESTO EN LA BASE DE DATOS AZURE SQL DATABASE EXTERNA ***/
 -- Crear una tabla para los registros a ser retornados a la base de datos 
 -- central.

 CREATE TABLE dbo.AccountDetails (
 AccountID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 AccountName VARCHAR(50) NULL,
 MailAddress VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 SubscriptionID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
 );
 INSERT INTO dbo.AccountDetails (AccountID, AccountName, MailAddress, SubscriptionID) VALUES (1, 'Wizard 1', 'some@where.com', '11111111-2222-3333-4444-000000000001');
 INSERT INTO dbo.AccountDetails (AccountID, AccountName, MailAddress, SubscriptionID) VALUES (2, 'Wizard 2', 'over@rainbow.com', '11111111-2222-3333-4444-000000000002');
 GO
 -- Crear procedimiento almacenado que va a retornar los registros de la base 
 -- de datos central

 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetAccountDetails10]
 (
 @SubscriptionID uniqueidentifier = NULL,
 @1SubscriptionID uniqueidentifier = NULL,
 @2SubscriptionID uniqueidentifier = NULL,
 @3SubscriptionID uniqueidentifier = NULL,
 @4SubscriptionID uniqueidentifier = NULL,
 @5SubscriptionID uniqueidentifier = NULL,
 @6SubscriptionID uniqueidentifier = NULL,
 @7SubscriptionID uniqueidentifier = NULL,
 @8SubscriptionID uniqueidentifier = NULL,
 @9SubscriptionID uniqueidentifier = NULL
 )
 AS
 begin
 SET NOCOUNT ON
 declare @SubIDs table (SubscriptionID uniqueidentifier);
 if @SubscriptionID is not null INSERT INTO @SubIDs (SubscriptionID) VALUES (@SubscriptionID);
 if @1SubscriptionID is not null INSERT INTO @SubIDs (SubscriptionID) VALUES (@1SubscriptionID);
 if @2SubscriptionID is not null INSERT INTO @SubIDs (SubscriptionID) VALUES (@2SubscriptionID);
 if @3SubscriptionID is not null INSERT INTO @SubIDs (SubscriptionID) VALUES (@3SubscriptionID);
 if @4SubscriptionID is not null INSERT INTO @SubIDs (SubscriptionID) VALUES (@4SubscriptionID);
 if @5SubscriptionID is not null INSERT INTO @SubIDs (SubscriptionID) VALUES (@5SubscriptionID);
 if @6SubscriptionID is not null INSERT INTO @SubIDs (SubscriptionID) VALUES (@6SubscriptionID);
 if @7SubscriptionID is not null INSERT INTO @SubIDs (SubscriptionID) VALUES (@7SubscriptionID);
 if @8SubscriptionID is not null INSERT INTO @SubIDs (SubscriptionID) VALUES (@8SubscriptionID);
 if @9SubscriptionID is not null INSERT INTO @SubIDs (SubscriptionID) VALUES (@9SubscriptionID);

select AccountID, AccountName, MailAddress, SubscriptionID from dbo.AccountDetails where SubscriptionID in (select SubscriptionID from @SubIDs);
 end;
 GO
 -- Probar:
 -- exec [sp_GetAccountDetails10] '11111111-2222-3333-4444-000000000001', '11111111-2222-3333-4444-000000000002', '4B1DE4FD-9051-4839-86BA-0000A5CCF12A'
```

(3) Crear una tabla central de ejemplo, extrae los IDs que se usaran en el “join”, y ejecuta el procedimiento almacenado remoto para traer los resultados:

```
/*** EJECUTAR ESTO EN LA BASE DE DATOS CENTRAL: ***/

 -- Crear una tabla temporal que aloja los IDs de interés
 -- Estos valores van a ser usados en el "join" a la table externa

 declare @Subscriptions TABLE (SubscriptionID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, SubscriptionName NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL);
 insert into @Subscriptions (SubscriptionID, SubscriptionName) values ('11111111-2222-3333-4444-000000000001', 'Subscription1');
 insert into @Subscriptions (SubscriptionID, SubscriptionName) values ('11111111-2222-3333-4444-000000000002', 'Subscription2');
 insert into @Subscriptions (SubscriptionID, SubscriptionName) values ('2150482E-D354-4E61-AF4D-38705F095C2C', 'Subscription3');

-- Preparar la cadena de caracteres de parámetro

 declare @subid_list nvarchar(500) = NULL, @cmd nvarchar(3000) = ''
 select top 10 @subid_list =
 case when @subid_list is null then '''' + cast(SubscriptionID as nvarchar(36)) + ''''
 else @subid_list + ', ''' + cast(SubscriptionID as nvarchar(36)) + ''''
 end
 from @Subscriptions

-- preparer el commando (cadena de caracteres)

 select @cmd = N'sp_GetAccountDetails10 ' + @subid_list
 -- select @cmd
 -- retorna: sp_GetAccountDetails10 '11111111-2222-3333-4444-000000000001', '11111111-2222-3333-4444-000000000002', '2150482E-D354-4E61-AF4D-38705F095C2C'

-- Ejecutar/llamar el procedimiento almacenado remote.

 EXEC sp_execute_remote @data_source_name = N'MyElasticDBQueryDataSrc', @stmt = @cmd;

-- solución alterna: ejecuta la instrucción SELECT directamente en la base de datos externa

 select @cmd = N'select AccountID, AccountName, MailAddress, SubscriptionID from dbo.AccountDetails where SubscriptionID in (' + @subid_list + ')'
 -- select @cmd
 -- retorna: select AccountID, AccountName, MailAddress, SubscriptionID from dbo.AccountDetails where SubscriptionID in ('11111111-2222-3333-4444-000000000001', '11111111-2222-3333-4444-000000000002', '2150482E-D354-4E61-AF4D-38705F095C2C')
 EXEC sp_execute_remote @data_source_name = N'MyElasticDBQueryDataSrc', @stmt = @cmd;
```

Comment: favor de leer [answer], por favor edita y coloca el ejemplo aquí y solo deja el enlace como referencia; si la página deja de estar disponible la info se pierde y la respuesta pierde valor

Comment: Gracias. Lo voy a hacer.

Comment: Listo @alfap. Gracias de nuevo.